# Cannot resolve domain name BIND server

Tags: bind

I have a BIND server, problem is that I can resolve domain name from bind server but other machines on the network cannot resolve domain name. Note all other machine can ping with IP address and firewalls are disabled. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup DNS for other machine in your network to use BIND as the resolver.

Check the client's `/etc/resolv.conf` to see if it has any reference to `nameserver x.x.x.x`, *where x.x.x.x is your BIND server IP...*